# C arrays, what will happen to my memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char

Reader,

Could anyone explain to me what will happen in my computer when I run this piece of false code.
Compiled with the gnu gcc compiler. in Codeblocks.

*This is false code:*

```
  char data[5];

  data[0] = '1';
  data[1] = '10';
  data[2] = '30';
  data[3] = '50';

  if(sizeof(data) == 5)
  {
  adjust(data);
  }
```

sizeof(data) is 5 because I declared *char data[5]*.

If I try to read data[1] I noticed it will return the last char. Either *'0'* or *'48'*.

So I was wondering, what happens with the '1' in data[1] and what will happen to my memory?

Comment: are char literals with more then one char accepted by the compiler (special cases like hex '0x1' i know are ) but in general?

Comment: apparently char literals are truncated to a single char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing that you're using multi-character literals like `10`, that probably adds to your confusion. What will happen with a line like this:

```
data[1] = '10';
```

is:

- The `int`-type (*not* `char`, in C) value `'10'` will be truncated down to `char`
- The resulting value will be assigned to `data[1]`.

Which value this is, exactly, is compiler-dependent since the literal is larger than what fits in a single `char`.

If you're seeing `0` (numerically 48 on ASCII systems), this means that `10` was truncated to `0`, which is the value stored. The `1` was then completely lost (not stored in an adjacent slot of the array, which you might have expected).

Answer (score 1):

Except for the effects of `adjust()`, what happens is quite clear:

- `data[]` is allocated with 5 elements
- the first through fourth elements are defined
- the size of `data[]` is compared with 5
- *adjust()* is called with a pointer to the beginning of `data[]`

I don't understand your comments about reading `data[1]`.  It contains something undefined until assigned.

`char x = '10';` is the same as `char x = '0'` on most architectures.  This is a departure in behavior from c++.  `char` expressions are handled as integers mostly, and then implicitly typecast upon storage.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer wallyk. I learned something new.